# Password Protection For pdf in PHP

Tags: php, pdf

> Developing an Admin page, in which admins uploads PDF and user downloads that PDF. After user downloads PDF, the PDF has to ask password, how to set password for that PDF automatically in php and that PDF should not set by Admin
>
> This is my Admin Page Code

```
  move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location);
if (copy($location, $location1)) {

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `at_uploads` WHERE  name='$name1'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {

        echo("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                     window.alert('File already exists with that name')
                     window.location.href='upload';
                      </SCRIPT>");
    }
}
```

> This is my user download page

```
if(isset($_GET['dow'])) {

$filepath1 = $_GET['dow'];

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `at_uploads` WHERE filepath1 ='$filepath1'");
while (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))) {

    $name=$row['name'];
    $location = "C:/wamp/www/school/admin/files/" . $name;
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');

    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($location) . '"');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($location));
    readfile($location);
      }
  }
```

> I don't know where to set password for pdf

Comment: you need to be more specific as to what you need. Also this would go a lot faster if you could provide your source code as well as where you made a mistake. i.e your error logs

Comment: which library r u using

Comment: But how should the user know the password if the admin can't set it? Or shoul the user reiceive the pdf and password seperate, e.g. file download directly and password per mail?

Comment: @TobiasF. admin will mail the password to user

Comment: Please check the [MCVE]

Comment: @Akin i updated my code

Comment: you need to download the library for this to work. You know right

Comment: @Akin i have tried fpdf, tcpdf they are setting password to pdf but after opening pdf showing empty page

Answer (score 0):

Which library are you using? If you are using FPdi, please use the function below.

```
<?php

function pdfEncrypt ($origFile, $password, $destFile){
//include the FPDI protection http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi-protection-128/
require_once('fpdi/FPDI_Protection.php');

$pdf =& new FPDI_Protection();
// set the format of the destinaton file, in our case 6×9 inch
$pdf->FPDF('P', 'in', array('6','9'));

//calculate the number of pages from the original document
$pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($origFile);

// copy all pages from the old unprotected pdf in the new one
for ($loop = 1; $loop <= $pagecount; $loop++) {
    $tplidx = $pdf->importPage($loop);
    $pdf->addPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplidx);
}

// protect the new pdf file, and allow no printing, copy etc and leave only reading allowed
$pdf->SetProtection(array(),$password);
$pdf->Output($destFile, 'F');

return $destFile;
}

//password for the pdf file
$password = 'info@yourdomain.com';

//name of the original file (unprotected)
$origFile = 'yourfilename.pdf';

//name of the destination file (password protected and printing rights removed)
$destFile ='yourfilename.pdf';

//encrypt the book and create the protected file
pdfEncrypt($origFile, $password, $destFile );
?>
```